# CORS errors accessing //polymer-project.org/components

Tags: http, cors, polymer

I'm trying to experiment with Polymer using the version of the Polymer components available for hosting on http://polymer-project.org until a real CDN shows up (as per the FAQ). Unfortunately importing components always fails with a CORS error.

Right now my code looks like this, and is hardly complex:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
  <script src="//polymer-project.org/components/platform/platform.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="//polymer-project.org/components/font-roboto/roboto.html"/> 
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

But I get this error out of Chrome when loading `roboto.html`:

> Redirect at origin 'http://polymer-project.org' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

This should work, right? `roboto.html` has been CORS-enabled, and I've verified that it's sending a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header, so why isn't this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The page `polymer-project.org/components/platform/platform.js` redirects to `www.polymer-project.org/components/platform/platform.js`. The former doesn't send an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Try referencing the resource with the `www` subdomain:

```
<script src="//www.polymer-project.org/components/platform/platform.js"></script>
```

Apply the same to the `roboto.html` reference: Although it doesn't cause errors, it's a useless redirect on each page view.